# Open svc file for WCF hosting

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, c#-4.0

I want to open a svc file to look at its code. But I always get svc.cs file opened automatically. Why?

I use visula studio 2010, c# 4.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the `.cs` is your code file... But in Visual Studio, right click the `.svc` file -> "View Markup". Unless you are creating a Service Factory or changing the Codebehind file I don't think there is much you can do.